# Opening and Saving a Web Page in Internet Explorer through Python

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, screen-scraping

I have written a python script to repeatedly hit a site using selenium and scrape a table of interest. I am not super well versed in web development. I did look through plenty of articles on urllib, requests, etc but am using selenium because this site uses a single sign on type authentication and it is well above my skill level to try and replicate that login through python (I think...). I can deal with the longer processing time and extra effort of selenium as long as I get the data in the end. Once I automate the clicks with selenium to get there I save the page source and parse it with beautifulsoup.

The page HTML looks something like this (I have obfuscated it a bit as it is a corporate website):

```
<TABLE><TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><B>abc<B></B></B></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TH title="Source - abc " class=tableHeader>
<DIV class=usageHeaderWithoutRefinements>abc </DIV></TH>
<TH title="Source - abc " class=tableHeader>
<DIV class=usageHeaderWithoutRefinements>abc </DIV></TH>
<TH title="Source - abc " class=tableHeader>
<DIV class=usageHeaderWithoutRefinements>abc </DIV></TH></TR>
<TR>
<TD title="Source - abc " class=tableData><A href="javascript:abcLink('1234')"><B>1234</B></A> </TD>
<TD title="Source - abc " class=tableData><A href="javascript:abcLink('1234')"><B>1234</B></A> </TD>
</TBODY></TABLE>
```

In the browser it is rendered as a table where the numbers like 1234 are hyperlinks to another page. I just want to store the numbers in the tables. Weirdly, it seems like sometimes when I run code like:

```
info_1 = soup.findAll('table')[0]
data_rows = part_info_1.findAll('tr')
data_1 = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td')] for i in range(len(data_rows))]
```

Sometimes it returns the table information but sometimes it returns an empty list. It seems like the Javascript is the problem.

My question: Is there a way to add to the python code above to pull out the info in the  tags without having to actually run the javascript or do anything similarly complicated? I'm hoping it is easy since the number is right there in the HTML but I mostly copied that code from another request for help and I'm not super comfortable extending so just asking. Alternatively, is there something simple I could do through python/selenium to make it so that when I use:

```
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

I can be sure that I always get the right table and not an empty list?

Thanks in advance.